# Uninstall php 7 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: javascript, php, ubuntu

I have a server that has an application that runs with PHP 5.6. But I upgraded the server from Ubuntu 14.04 to 18.04 and in the process I also upgraded PHP to 7.2.
Now I'm trying to uninstall it but I'm finding difficult.

I have run the command:

`sudo apt-get remove php`

and

`sudo apt-get remove --purge php`

Its says that PHP it's not installed, but running 
`php --version`
I'm still seeing the version 7 of PHP.

> PHP 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 (cli) (built: Aug 12 2019 19:34:28) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

Comment: try: `sudo apt-get purge php7.*`

Comment: It might have been installed manually (via make, make install) and therefore is is not registered in apt (looking at the output of `which php` **might** give some clues).

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Have you checked whether there are other packages with a similar name that need to be removed?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

This will remove all php7 versions, be it php 7.0 or php 7.1 etc..

```
sudo apt-get purge php7.*
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

- `apt/apt-get autoclean` → cleans obsolete deb-packages, less than `clean`
- `apt/apt-get autoremove` → removes orphaned packages which are not longer needed from the system, but not purges them, use the `--purge` option together with the command for that.

**To Install PHP again **

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

if **php7.0**

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

if **php7.1**

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1
```

if **php7.2**

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2
```

To **switch that to the newer 7.1,7.2,7.3,7.4 version**, first disable older **PHP version**:

```
user@test:~# sudo a2dismod php7.0
```

Then **enable PHP 7.2**:

```
user@test:~# sudo a2enmod php7.2
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Install all the required extension, so it won't make any error in future.
Replace command based on your version. I used 7.2 as I have installed that version.

```
sudo apt install php7.2-common php7.2-mysql php7.2-xml php7.2-xmlrpc php7.2-curl php7.2-gd php7.2-imagick php7.2-cli php7.2-dev php7.2-imap php7.2-mbstring php7.2-opcache php7.2-soap php7.2-zip php7.2-intl -y
```

Comment: need to correct 
   |     sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

Comment: thanks for the commands. I'm having difficulty with 7.4
Getting messages like these: 

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package php7.4-mysql

E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-mysql'

E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-mysql'

E: Unable to locate package php7.4-xml

E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-xml'

E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-xml'

E: Unable to locate package php7.4-xmlrpc

Since I'm a windows guy don't have any idea :D

Comment: At this point `ppa:ondrej/php`No longer supports < php74 in Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly you need to restart the apache to take all in effect and also
You can install mutliple php version using this [post](https://www.key2goal.com/article/install-multiple-php-73-72-71-ubuntu-1804-ubuntu-1604)
or just using

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y php5.6 php5.6-cli php5.6-common
```

disable php7.2:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2
```

enable php 5.6:

```
sudo a2enmod php5.6
```

After all restart the apache again to take into affect

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: it help me with the installation of the exact PHP I needed

Comment: Nice to hear that, Great

Answer (score 2):

This will remove PHP

```
sudo apt-get purge `dpkg -l | grep php7.2| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "`
sudo apt-get purge php7.*
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
whereis php
sudo rm -rf /etc/php
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Just run

`sudo apt-get purge 'php*'`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall PHP

```
sudo apt-get remove –purge php*
sudo apt-get purge php*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get remove dbconfig-php
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

The output of the below command will provide you with information on the installed package software, version, architecture, and a short description of the package. grep command is used to find the PHP package

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep php | cut -f 1
```

sudo apt-get remove --purge 
sudo whereis php
sudo rm -rf <directory/file path from the previous command output>

Comment: This solution can mess someone up

Answer (score 1):

**apt-mark to the rescue**

I think it is a good idea to point out the existence of `apt-mark hold <package-name>`.
Once you have a specific version installed that you want to keep, you can prevent accidental upgrades. So you can run `apt upgrade`, `apt full-upgrade` and don't need to worry about which PHP version you will end up with.
That said, you also prevent scenarios (as seen with the commenters above) where you end up with multiple major and main releases installed next to each other at the same time.

For example, if you have PHP 7.4 installed, and your App doesn't support PHP 8.* yet, then:

```
apt-mark hold php7.4-common
apt-mark hold php7.4-fpm
```

Answer (score -2):

This is work on my server:

```
sudo apt purge php5.6 php5.6-common
sudo apt purge php7.x php7.x-common
```

Comment: Please share more details. Why did you need to purge any PHP 5.6 related package to remove PHP 7?

Comment: Just to get the fresh install lol